# Can I validate file format of the file within a zip file, using Playwright?

Tags: javascript, automation, playwright, playwright-test

I have a scenario where I need to download a file using Playwright.
When I download, I get the file in a zip format. How can I validate the file format of the actual file that is zipped. While validating manually, I can extract it and see the file format.
How can I do it with Playwright automation? (I'm working with Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You may use nodeJS fs & unzip modules for verifying file extensions inside zip file.

```
const unzip = require('unzip'),
    fs    = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    inputFileName = '/home/user/Downloads/SomeFile.zip'; // zip file path 

fs.createReadStream(inputFileName)
    .pipe(unzip.Parse())
    .on('entry', (entry) => {
        const rest_file_path = ['.js', '.exe', '.zip'],
            extension = path.extname(entry.path);
        if (rest_file_path.includes(extension)) {
            console.log(`Found the expected file extensions`) 

        }
        
    });
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip

Comment: @Krishna, did it resolve your issue? If it helped, please accept the answer.